# Adding XCopy command through Post Build Event in Visual Studio 2008 for multiple commands

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

I wanted to add 2 simple XCOPY commands to a post build event for a class file in Visual Studio 2008.

However, Visual Studio doesn't want to run the command unless I've either run the command once from a command line, OR copied the specified files to the target directory first.

Is it possible to specify or suppress/default the /f flag without having to execute the commands first?

```
xcopy /y "C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\My Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\TrainingProject\TrainingProject\bin\debug\TrainingProject.dll" "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\slxclient\bin\TrainingProject.dll"
xcopy /y "C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\My Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\TrainingProject\TrainingProject\bin\debug\TrainingProject.pdb" "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\slxclient\bin\TrainingProject.pdb"
```

The PDB entry chokes if I have not already copied it manually.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just don't include the filename in the target path:

> if not exist c:\bar\bin md c:\bar\bin
>   xcopy /y c:\foo\bin\mumble.pdb c:\bar\bin